# SPL to PPL(A) conversion

Tags: easa-regulations, glider, ppl

I'm currently flying with gliders as a hobby whilst getting my SPL for it. (Belgium - EASA) I know there is SPL TMG and PPL(A) TMG. (don't know the difference) Once I get to PPL(A) TMG, I want to get my SEP rating, IR, MEP, etc...

In what options is this possible? If so, how many hours would I need for each phase of the trajectory?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this and all are subject to change based on EASA Part-FCL. I recommend this document. just translate it to your language or English:
https://www.fliegeninaachen.de/downloads/Umschulung.pdf

Part-FCL is your single source of truth.